# QGIS dissolve is changing the shape of polygons rather than just combining them

Tags: qgis, dissolve

QGIS novice here.  I have a shapefile for US census PUMA (public use microdata areas).  One of the attributes in my shapefile is the metropolitan area of the PUMA.  I want to combine PUMA's which are located in the same metropolitan area.  To do this, I am using the dissolve command, and choosing the metropolitan area attribute as the dissolve field.  For most of the United States, things work as expected, but there are a few areas in which there is weird behaviour.  For example, instead of combining the Chicago pumas into a big polygon, QGIS redraws a Chicago polygon of slightly different size.  See the following pictures to see what I mean:

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Is this a QGIS bug, or is there something I am doing wrong?  Is there anything I might try to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Are all the files in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Yes the project is all in WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator.  The only input shape file is the PUMA data from the census.

Comment: @dof1985 points out below that I was actually using NAD83, ESPG: 4269 (as can be seen in the lower right hand corner of the images included in my question).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing GRASS, importing the shapefile there, and running v.dissolve using the metropolitan area attribute.  The dissolve worked flawlessly as expected.

Comment: It is very interesting, your problem there. I wonder what was the cause of it. BTW note that you are not in Pseudo Mercator - rather you were at NAD83, ESPG: 4269

Comment: Oh, yes, I reported that incorrectly.  I'll add that as an edit above.